# If both USB memsticks and SSD disks use the same technology, why does only the latter "forget" data?

Tags: usb, ssd, usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure, compact-flash

I recently learned (or was tricked into believing) that SSD disks actually **forget** all their data on them if left unpowered for just a year.

Assuming that this is true, and I've spent more than enough time trying to debunk it, how then can my USB memsticks, memory cards in my EverDrives and even my Sony PlayStation memory card from the 1990s still hold data while being powered on once every few years?

Nothing that's claimed online seems to ever actually be the case. SSDs must be using some other technology which has much faster performance but at the price of nonexistent archival value?

I wish there were a clear, correct table showing all current storage media technologies and how long they last while powered off and other data like that. It's impossible to find, like everything else I search for.

Comment: this was true for ssds, not so much anymore.

Answer (score 3):

While this is true that flash memory does have a limited data retention period when unpowered, there is no such a magic number "one year retention". It all depends on many factors: operating temperature, storage temperature, overall wearout, single or multi level cells (SLC/MLC/TLC...), lithography size (10nm/7nm...),...

USB keys and SSD drive both use flash memory, but not of the same grade. SSDs aim at high performances, which requires for instance a thin lithography, and a thin lithography also means a lower retention period.

https://www.anandtech.com/show/9248/the-truth-about-ssd-data-retention

Comment: That article is a bunch of "say nothing" garbage.  It uses the words "unpowered" twice, once to describe the media reports are false and the other statement indicating "its bad news" but in both cases the proceeding sentences say absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Ramhound the article is accurate and based on industry reference documents like this one: https://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/Alvin_Cox%20[Compatibility%20Mode]_0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is a real issue but not as one dimensional as you paint it and the one year is probably exaggerated. I can not understand you can not find info on the matter, I find plenty, for example [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yixinluo/index_files/data-retention_fms15.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eyixinluo/index_files/data-retention_fms15.pdf).

Look for "NAND flash data retention" and you should be able to find plenty more.

FWIW I recover data from mainly USB flash drives and memory cards using so called chip-off method and in general the quality of the NAND used on these devices is lower than the NAND used in SSD drives.

I've recovered USB flash drives that have been in drawers for a few years and basically impossible to read using for example a DeepSpar data recovery hardware. Often it's a litany of read errors, but often the flash drive's controller simply hangs being unable to cope with the amount of errors or even worse the firmware itself has corrupted, basically because it 'leaked data': It's stored on the same NAND as the user data.

But, nothing else happened to the device other than just living in it's drawer.

Let me give you a clumsy explanation how this illustrates this data leakage thing.

These are often poor quality devices, but not always. Each NAND device leaks data over time when left unpowered. Using a specialized NAND reader + software it is some times possible to improve recovery quality using so called RR or read retry registers. Simply put a NAND cell is either 1 or 0 based on the charge level inside the cell (of course not true for MLC etc., trying to keep this simple). As electrons escape this charge drops too, to the point where it goes below threshold that decided 1 or 0. Using RR registers we can then convince the NAND to modify the threshold value, IOW accept smaller charge to represent 1 rather than 0.

This is actually a method to counter the data leakage phenomenon to allow us to recover data from such NAND chips. Of course there's a point where our 'tricks' will fail to work.

[image: modifying NAND threshold using RR]